# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange

Tags: android, eclipse

Very new to Android and trying to install a Android project from an SVN server. I have been able to get this project to work today on an Windows computer, but not on my Mac OS X 10.5.8.

When I run the project, I get the following error

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange
```

I have looked at other solutions for similar problems and have tried:

1. Updating Eclipse to the new version through Eclipse->Check for Updates
2. Cleaning, Rebuilding and Restarting Eclipse
3. Tried deleting the bin & gen folders
4. Made sure the build path was correct and the bin folder was not included

Eclipse Version= 3.7.0
The project is using Android 2.2 as minimum sdk

First question so please let me know if I am missing any information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be it's because [java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) is available since [API Level 9 aka Android 2.3](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html)?

Comment: You are correct @darkmist that java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange is only in  API level 9. The strange part about this is that I searched through all the code and could not find copyOfRange. But by upgrading to a higher API level, the application started to work. I then revert back to Android 2.2 and the application now runs on that without any problems.